# Problem with choosing a folder to store collections and database

Tags: mongodb

I got a error with mongod -- dbpath

My command in mongo shell:
mongod --dbpath C:\BooksData
Answer:
[js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:9

Comment: did you checked if you have permissions to right on the c: ? also is the BookData folder already created under c drive ? if not Mongodb is going to throw an error.

Comment: I created a folder. How I can check premissions to righ in the c?

Comment: `mongod` is an executable. Run it from the command line instead of from inside the `mongo` shell.

Comment: thx. I understand.Maybe it is right solution...

Comment: kevinadi, can you help me with ajax requests? - I must send POST request in my  ASP.NET Core server with url : 'api/books' . How I can do this ?- Some weeks try to find answer...